# MySQL update multiple rows based on id

Tags: mysql, database

In a table in MySQL I'm trying to update a specific field based on the id.

The table has more than 5,000 rows and many fields. One of the fields is `"id"` and another one that I want to update is called `"category"` which right now all of them are NULL and I want to update all of them.

my backup mysql file that I want to use has only `"id"` and `"category"` which they are like this:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `category`) VALUES
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, 2),
(6, 1),
(7, 5),
(8, 1),
(9, 6),
(10, 1),
...
(5000, 3);
```

I want to update the "category" field in my table according to the id's in this list and because there is more than 5,000 rows I don't want to change each record manually.

Right now in my table all the "category" fields are NULL and I want to update or give new information to the "category" fields using the file that I have.

Comment: why are you working witha backup file in the first place?

Comment: @Juan I migrated from another script and this is an old backup which I'm trying to use

Comment: @DanielE. Right now in my table all the "category" fields are NULL I want to give new information to the "category" fields using the file that I have.

Comment: You can truncate the table and import again or you use **ON DUPLICATE KEY ..**

Comment: I would import the old table with a different name as an auxiliary table, and then run an update query on the table with null category selecting the new value from the auxiliary table based on the common product id.

Comment: @Juan can you give me an the update query code according to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to use a Temporary table :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_products (id int, category int ) ;
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO `temp_products` (`id`, `category`) VALUES
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, 2),
(6, 1),
(7, 5),
(8, 1),
(9, 6),
(10, 1),
...
(5000, 3);
```

Now you just have to use an update with an inner join :

```
Update products p
INNER JOIN temp_products t_p ON t_p.id = p.id
SET p.category = t_p.category
```

if you want you can add a **where** clause :

```
Update products p
INNER JOIN temp_products t_p ON t_p.id = p.id
SET p.category = t_p.category
WHERE p.category IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the better solution for you can be:

First of all, create temporary table

```
 CREATE TABLE `products_tmp` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `category` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
```

After that, perform inserts into generated temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO `products_tmp` (`id`, `category`) VALUES
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, 2),
(6, 1),
(7, 5),
(8, 1),
(9, 6),
(10, 1),
...
(5000, 3);
```

after this, you can update all fields in your original table:

```
UPDATE products p
JOIN products_tmp pt ON p.id = pt.id
SET p.category = pt.category;
```

After this, you can delete temporary table

```
drop table products_tmp;
```